# Google Tag Manager: Tracking of values of a formular field

Tags: javascript

i want to track the chosen destination within a formular with the GTM.

For this I made a variable with custom js:

```
function() {
  var inputField = document.getElementById("country");
  return inputField.value || "";
}
```

When I test it in preview mode i get back the correct chosen answer, but not the wanted value:

For example: I chose USA within the formular:

```
<option value="2">USA</option>
```

I get back "2" and not "USA".
But I want to the value "USA" in my dataLayer

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `return inputField.innerHTML;`

Comment: @cFreed — That will give you a bunch of `<option>` elements in a string. Not very useful.

Comment: @Quentin Uh! Pretty stupid, indeed... I don't know how I could write this. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are asking for the value, which is `2`.

To get the text of the selected option, you'll need to find the option element that is selected and then get its text.

```js
var select = document.getElementById("country");
var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
var text = option.text;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<select id=country>
    <option value=1>          One
    <option value=2 selected> Two
    <option value=3>          Three
</select>
```